# MySQL Query to a Zend DB Select

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-select

I have a MySQL standard query that I need to convert into a `Zend_Db_Select` but I can't get it to work.

I get this error:

```
Select query cannot join with another table
```

Here's the query:

```php
// THE COUNTER
$subselect = $this->table->select()->from(
        array('x' => 'blog_comments'),
        array('x.post_id', new Zend_Db_Expr('count(*) as comments')))
    ->group('post_id');
// THE TOTAL SELECT
$select->from(array('p' => 'blog_posts'), array('p.*'))
       ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->joinLeft(array(
           'x' => $subselect,
           'x.post_id = p.id', 
           array()
           )
       );
```

If someone can convert this, it would be great because I need that in `select()` mode because I use `Zend_Pagination`.

For those who want the full PHP function: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ULGAp3cg) and the stack traces: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jpyqSx35).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need: `setIntegrityCheck(false)` - review: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html for more information

```
$select = $this->select()
->from(params) 
->setIntegrityCheck(false) 
->joinLeft(params)
->where(params);
```

Comment: I get a `Error 1064`. `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `x` ON x.post_id = p.id ORDER BY `created_date` DESC LIMIT 10' at line 2`

Answer (score 1):

As Michael already mentioned, you need `setIntegrityCheck(false)` in order to do joins with other tables using `Zend_Db_Select`.

`Error 1064` is kind of ambiguous and encompasses all kinds of query syntax issues. So I suggest you wrap the sub query in parenthesis:

```
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array('p' => 'blog_posts'), array('p.*'))
    ->joinLeft(array(
        'x' => new Zend_Db_Expr("({$subselect})"), 
        'x.post_id = p.id', 
        array()
    ));
```

If *that* doesn't work well then there must be something wrong with your sub-select. Try `echo $subselect;` which will invoke the `__toString()` [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) and show you your query.

Answer (score 1):

The Expression is the `Count(*)` statement, not the whole subquery.

```
$subselect = $this->table->select()->from(
    array('x' => 'blog_comments'),
    array('x.post_id', new Zend_Db_Expr('count(*) as comments'))
)->group('post_id');

$select->from(array('p' => 'blog_posts'), array('p.*'))
    ->joinLeft(array(
        'x' => $subselect,
        'x.post_id = p.id', 
        array()
    ));
```

I'm not really sure you actually need to have a subquery. Regardless start out with a simple join and build on it.

```
//getGateway = whatever method used to access the database adapter.
//SetIntegrityCheck(false) locks the tables from writes allowing tables to be joined
$select = $this->getGateway()->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->from('blog_posts');//default $cols = *
$select->join('blog_comments', 'blog_comments.post_id' = 'blog_posts.post_id');//does it really matter what kind of join you use? They all work the same so use whichever you like.
$select->group('blog_comments.post_id');
```

once you get the query working with the defaults you can refine it until it work how you want.

If you are doing a query to use paginator a `count()` expression is kind of useless as paginator will apply a limit and offset to every query.

Also you might consider executing this query in reverse. You might be better off joining in the other direction or just executing a query only on the comments table. Without seeing the rest of your structure it's kinda hard to tell.

Good Luck.

Comment: Hmm, I forgot to specify that the paginator is only used to paginate the blog posts. The whole thing is more about counting comments for each posts using a join or something else...

Comment: Then why join at all just query as required using a where() against the post_id which is likely a foreign key or at least an index. Personally i'd just use a getComments() method from an entity model, but it doesn't look like you're structured to support that.

Comment: Nop, I'm not supporting that kind of model. But my link between the post and the comment is not a foreign key, it's just a reference.

Comment: I'm still getting this error even using `setIntegrityCheck(false)` : `Message: Select query cannot join with another table`

Comment: update your question and put your query in context. Where are you doing the query? In the controller, in a DbTable Model or in a different kind of model? This info might help troubleshoot

Comment: See the edit. And the query is made in a model who include a DbTable.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly made it in an other way.

I use my `CMW_Model_Comments` within the view to get the number of comment by the post ID.

```php
// IN MY VIEW
echo $this->commentor->getCommentCount($post->id);

// IN MY CONTROLLER
$cmt = new CMW_Model_Comments();
$this->view->commentor = $cmt;
```

It works perfectly!